# How to retrieve value of an attribute which contains colon in the attribute name using xpath

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser

I have a simple requirement where in I need to fetch the value of attribute `xml:id` i.e `af1`.
I am making use of a `SAXParser` and here is my `xpath:a/aff/@xml:id` on the contrary I was able to fetch value of using the `xpath:a/aff/@value`.

But i was unable to retrieve the value could you please help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<a>
   <aff xml:id="af1" value="a">
        <uAff>
            Hello
        </uAff>
    </aff>
    <aff xml:id="corr1">
        <uAff>
            Hello1
        </uAff>
    </aff>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get the value of the attributes you could use:

```
/a/aff/@*[name()='xml:id']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) Your answer was SPOT ON :-)

Can u please tell how to get value of the tag which has colon.Say instead of aff if it was aff:a, how can we parse it?

Comment: if you have aff:a then aff must be a namespace, and that is a different problem. have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536441/xpath-namespace-driving-me-crazy

Comment: or you can use local-name() instead of name(), FWIW http://stackoverflow.com/a/11131700/32453

Comment: I am not an expert on xpath but it seems if you reach an attribute you can always access its parent element by adding a /.. [slash double dot] at the end i.e. : `"//@*[name()='xml:id' and .='corr1']/.."`

Answer (score 1):

/a/aff/@xml:id works just fine in getting the values...

Are you trying to get both values?

If you are trying to get just the first value you could use /a/aff[1]/@xml:id

Comment: Your answer is correct if there is no colon, but when there is a colon it doesnt fetch the attribute value with /a/aff/@xml:id this xpath.