# Searching for xpath expression with colon in attribute name throws exception (node.js elementtree module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, elementtree

Using the elementtree package in nodejs, I'm trying to verify the existence of a certain xml attribute in an xml file (specifically an android manifest file).

```
var manifestTxt = fs.readFileSync('AndroidManifest.xml', 'utf-8'),
    manifestDoc = new et.ElementTree(et.XML(manifestTxt)),
    expected = 'application/activity[@android:name="com.whatever.app"]';

test.ok(manifestDoc.find(expected));
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementpath.js:210
      throw new SyntaxError(token, 'Invalid attribute predicate');
        ^
Error: Invalid attribute predicate
```

It doesn't seem to like the colon in the attribute name, but without it the search doesn't match. I think I'm handling the namespace wrong -- but can't find the proper way.

**Edit** Here's the sample xml I'm searching:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">&#xA; 
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.whatever.app">&#xA;                
            <intent-filter>&#xA;</intent-filter>
        </activity> 
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the colon `\:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementtree expects namespace URIs, not namespace prefixes.

```
var manifestTxt = fs.readFileSync('AndroidManifest.xml', 'utf-8'),
    manifestDoc = new et.ElementTree(et.XML(manifestTxt)),
    expected = '//application/activity[@{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}name="com.whatever.app"]';

test.ok( manifestDoc.find(expected) );
```

See: [ElementTree: Working with Qualified Names](http://effbot.org/zone/element-qnames.htm)

---

**Edit** The XPath implementation of [node-elementtree](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree) does not [currently](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree/blob/5cb7ec5aab2ceeeae5f48549579880db9be857d3/lib/elementpath.js) seem to have namespace support at all.

Missing that you'd have to do some legwork:

```
var manifestTxt = fs.readFileSync('AndroidManifest.xml', 'utf-8'),
    manifestDoc = new et.ElementTree(et.XML(manifestTxt)),
    activities = manifestDoc.findall('//application/activity'), i;

for (i=0; i<activities.length; i++) {
  if ( activities[i].attrib['android:name'] === 'com.whatever.app' ) {
    test.ok(true);
  }
}
```

The line `if ( activities[i].attrib['android:name'] === 'com.whatever.app' ) {` is largely a guess.

I don't know how the parser handles namespaced attributes. When in doubt, just dump the whole `activities[i].attrib` to the console and see what the parser did. Adapt the above code accordingly. I'm afraid that's as close as you will get with that kind of limited XPath support.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, and though it no longer threw the exception, the find failed (so I figured it was also wrong). I've added the sample xml that I'm searching. So the question then becomes, why does the find fail?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev That's right. Anyway, that's how ElementTree works as per the documentation (see the "Working with qualified names" link above). I can't do very much about it.

Comment: @wildabeast Looking at [the source](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree/blob/master/lib/elementpath.js), I don't see any indication that node-elementtree even *has* namespace support. The XPath implementation is extremely basic. There is no function support, either. Can you confirm that this is the version you're using?

Comment: Thats the version I'm using, yes. So you're probably right about the lack of namespace support. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**In case you don't have the information how to register the namespace and use the associated prefix for it, use**:

```
application/activity
   [@*[local-name()=name' 
     and 
      namespace-uri() = 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
      ] 
   = 
    'com.whatever.app'
   ]
```

**Simpler expressions that aren't safe in the general case, but may select the wanted node(s) in this specific case**:

```
application/activity[@*[local-name()='name'] = 'com.whatever.app']
```

**or this expression**:

```
application/activity[@*[name()='android:name'] = 'com.whatever.app']
```