# How to select xml elements by an attribute name containing a colon in PHP (domx)?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, domxpath

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894696/how-to-retrieve-value-of-an-attribute-which-contains-colon-in-the-attribute-name), I am trying to select xml elements by their attribute name, which contains a colon.

I am trying to do this with PHP, and my final goal is, to replace the content of these elements.

My code does not return any result:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<a>
<aff xml:id="af1" value="a">
    <uAff>
        Hello
    </uAff>
</aff>
<aff xml:id="corr1">
    <uAff>
        Hello1
    </uAff>
</aff>
</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xelems = $xpath->query("/a/aff/@*[name()='xml:id']");
print_r($xelems);

foreach ($xelems as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = 'New attribute value'; // changes the value of the xml:id attribute.';
   $node->parentNode->nodeValue = 'This does work!'; // changes the value of the element
}
echo htmlentities($dom->saveHTML());
```

How can this work with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is XML, so use `loadXML` instead of `loadHTML`.

`*` selects elements. `@*` selects attributes.

```xml
@*[name()='xml:id']
```

You might also need to start the expression by `//` to make it search everywhere, not just under the root node.

But then, much simpler expression might be used:

```xml
//@xml:id
```

or, with the full path

```xml
/a/aff/@xml:id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Not sure why I did not try this before. You made my day!