# Trouble reading iTunes XML feed

Tags: c#, xml, rss, itunes

I am trying to read an XML feed from http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=10/genre=2/xml.

I want to access the fields like this:

```
<im:price amount="1.29000" currency="USD">$1.29</im:price>
<im:releaseDate label="December 31, 1960">1960-12-31T16:00:00-07:00</im:releaseDate>
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var xml = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=10/genre=2/xml";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
XmlNodeList items = doc.SelectNodes("//entry");
foreach (var item in items) {
    // Do something with item.
}
```

No luck, though.  `items` is null.  Why?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you got in `item` in `foreach` loop?

Comment: He can get anything since `items` is null..

Comment: @pwas: it's not null, it's a collection with 0 elements.

Comment: Hmm, OP claims that `items` is null. So I think he is getting `NullReferenceException` or something.

Comment: @pwas: Just tested this, it's not null :).

Comment: Ok, then all right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a namespace manager to map the RSS and also the iTunes custom tags namespace URIs to short prefixes (itunes and im in the example below):

```
var xml = "http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=10/genre=2/xml";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xml);
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("itunes", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("im", "http://itunes.apple.com/rss");

XmlNodeList items = doc.SelectNodes("//itunes:entry", namespaceManager);
foreach (XmlNode item in items)
{
    var price = item.SelectSingleNode("im:price", namespaceManager);
    var releaseDate = item.SelectSingleNode("im:releaseDate", namespaceManager);

    if (price != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(price.Attributes["amount"].InnerText);
    }

    if (releaseDate != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(releaseDate.Attributes["label"].InnerText);
    }
}
```

For that specific feed you should get 10 entries.

It's in the [docs as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that
>   the namespace URI is the empty namespace. If your XML includes a
>   default namespace, you must still use the XmlNamespaceManager and add
>   a prefix and namespace URI to it; otherwise, you will not get any
>   nodes selected. For more information, see Select Nodes Using XPath
>   Navigation.

Alternatively you can use a namespace-agnostic XPath (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/536529/1119545)):

```
XmlNodeList items = doc.SelectNodes("//*[local-name() = 'entry']");
```

Finally, not sure why you said items is null. It cannot be. When running your original code you should get this:

[image]

Comment: sorry, my mistake. its not null, but 0 items. how i am gona get the the items <im:price and other. thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: @Parminder: No problem. I updated the answer anyway.

Comment: for price it throws an error Namespace prefix 'im' is not defined.

Comment: @Parminder: Check my entire answer. I have also registered the `im` namespace.

Comment: the strange thing is, it repeates same entry 10 times. what could be the problem ?

Comment: @Parminder: Yes, indeed. The XPaths for price and release date were incorrect. Check update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58672/discussion-between-parminder-and-marcel-n).