# XPath on an XML document with namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I'm having this XML document with namespaces and I want to extract some nodes using XPath.

Here's the document:

```
<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <anyType xsi:type="Document">
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Title>T1</Title>
  </anyType>

  <anyType xsi:type="Document">
    <Id>15</Id>
    <Title>T15</Title>
  </anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

What's the XPath expression going to be if I want to extract all "anyType" elements with xsi:type="Document"?

I've tried this:

```
//anyType[@xsi:type="Document"]
```

and it doesn't work:

Comment: which version of xpath are you using? xpath versions handle namespaces differently?

Comment: Duped: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536441/xpath-namespace-driving-me-crazy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345/xpaths-and-default-namespaces - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103576/whats-wrong-with-my-xpath-xml

Comment: Looks like I have to say: '//xmlns:anyType[@xsi:type="Document"]' for it to work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using C# then you need to specify the namespace for the "anyType" element in your XPath:

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml( "your xml" );
var names = new XmlNamespaceManager( xml.NameTable );
names.AddNamespace( "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" );
names.AddNamespace( "a", "http://tempuri.org/" );
var nodes = xml.SelectNodes( "//a:anyType[@xsi:type='Document']", names );
```

Comment: What is up with `a:anyType`? Is that some sort of magic value?

Comment: No, that's the name of the XML element being sought in the above question.

Comment: ah, I see, didn't scroll over far enough

Answer (score 0):

I think that

```
//anyType[namespace-uri() = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"][local-name() = "type"]
```

Will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think what's wrong in my original expression is I need to prefix anyType with the namespace "xmlns".

Answer (score 0):

This way you don't need to specify namespace:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml("your xml");
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name() = 'anyType']");
XmlNode nodeToImport = xmlDoc2.ImportNode(node, true);
xmlDoc2.AppendChild(nodeToImport);
```

Answer (score -1):

Had nearly the same problem, I forgot to add the correct namespace for xsi:type
(http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance) was using http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
and I did never get any result - now it is working the following way:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/item1/item2/item3/@xsi:type"></xsl:value-of>
```