# Read xml attribute in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have been searching this for a while and cannot find a solution.  I have an xml that is returned from a HttpWebRequest that I load into an xmldocument and I am trying to get a specific attribute (status) of the request.  The xml that is returned is below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  >
  <soapenv:Body>
    <processRequestResponse>
      <parameters>
        <ns1:searchResponse status="success" xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0:search">
          <ns1:pso>
            <ns2:psoID ID="Users:####" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0"/>
            <ns3:data xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0">
              <ns4:attr name="Users.User ID" xmlns:ns4="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core">
                <ns4:value></ns4:value>
              </ns4:attr>
            </ns3:data>
          </ns1:pso>
        </ns1:searchResponse>
      </parameters>
    </processRequestResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My code that I am using to get this data is below.

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string returnResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(returnResponse);

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode searchResponse = root.SelectSingleNode("Envelope/Body/processRequestResponse/parameters/searchResponse");
XmlAttribute status = (XmlAttribute)searchResponse.Attributes.GetNamedItem("status");
if (status != null)
{
    string statusReturn = status.Value;
    return statusReturn;
}
else
{
    return "value is null";
}
```

Any help you can give in the status value would be appreciated.  I keep getting an object reference error at the xmlattrbute status line.

Comment: Please indent your XML sample, it's impossible to read which makes it hard to tell what you're trying to extract.

Answer (score 3):

Your XML document includes namespaces. You will need to account for the namespaces in the XML document before any XPath queries will work.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561822/xpath-on-an-xml-document-with-namespace) for how to add these namespaces in your C# code and reference them in your XPath; or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536441/xpath-namespace-driving-me-crazy) for how to use wildcard matching (though in your case that's going to get messy, since you have to do it for every element name.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
        const string ValueIsNull = "value is null";
        string returnResponse;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response == null)
            {
                return ValueIsNull;
            }

            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream == null)
                {
                    return ValueIsNull;
                }

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    returnResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        var doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.LoadXml(returnResponse);

        var namespaces = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        namespaces.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        namespaces.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        namespaces.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        namespaces.AddNamespace("ns1", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0:search");
        namespaces.AddNamespace("ns2", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0");
        namespaces.AddNamespace("ns3", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SPML:2:0");
        namespaces.AddNamespace("ns4", "urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core");

        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        if (root == null)
        {
            return ValueIsNull;
        }

        var searchResponse = root.SelectSingleNode("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/processRequestResponse/parameters/ns1:searchResponse", namespaces);

        if ((searchResponse == null) || (searchResponse.Attributes == null))
        {
            return ValueIsNull;
        }

        var status = (XmlAttribute)searchResponse.Attributes.GetNamedItem("status");

        return status == null ? ValueIsNull : status.Value;
```