# Changing values in XML file

Tags: c#

I need to change password values in my configuration.xml .

Password need to be changed for following users :

1. tsuer1
2. github
3. wtsntro
4. wtsntrw and so on.

Format of configuration.xml file is like following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
  <extensions>
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" />
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp" />
    <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3" />
  </extensions>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="SERVER" value="JBOSS" />
    <property name="FTP_USER" value="adobenet\wtsntrw" />
    <property name="FTP_PASSWORD" value="password value" />
    <property name="FTP_READ_USER" value="adobenet\\wtsntro" />
    <property name="FTP_READ_PASS" value="password value" />
    <property name="API_SECRET_KEY" value="wxrocks" />
    <property name="API_ENV" value="regular" />
    <property name="PRERELEASE_PASSWORD" value="prerelease" />
    <property name="watson.git_user" value="github" />
    <property name="watson.git_pwd" value="password value" />
    <property name="teststudio.user" value="tsuser1" />
    <property name="teststudio.pwd" value="password value" />
  </system-properties>
</server>
```

And following is the code i tried but failed :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string path = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\configuration.xml";  // location of configuration.xml file.
            doc.Load(path);
            // Using foreach loop for specific Xmlnodes.
            foreach (XmlNode selectNode in doc.SelectNodes("server/system-properties/property"))
            {
                if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "teststudio.pwd")  // tsuser1
                {
                    selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new password";  // changes password value for "FTP_USER".
                }

                if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "watson.git_pwd")   //github
                {
                    selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new passwordx";  // changes password value for "FTP_READ_USER".
                }
                if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "FTP_READ_PASS")   // wtsntro
                {
                    selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new_passwordy";  // changes password value for "FTP_PASSWORD".
                }
            }

            doc.Save(path);  // Save changes.
            Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What did it fail with?

Comment: Right, but i think there is some problem with the doc.SelectNodes ?

Comment: @Romoku : It doesn't give any error message but still fails to perform changes in configuration.xml file.

Comment: @AseemKamaal Debug it and find out why.

Comment: @aevitas: I debugged it and find that my code fails to go into foreach loop. Seems some problem in doc.SelectNodes

Comment: @AseemKamaal Alright, you probably should include that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xml elements are contained in a NameSpace, so your XPath needs to account for that.

See:

[XPath on an XML document with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561822/xpath-on-an-xml-document-with-namespace)

[XML Namespaces and How They Affect XPath and XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

var nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nm.AddNamespace("jb", "urn:jboss:domain:1.2");

foreach (XmlNode selectNode in doc.SelectNodes("jb:server/jb:system-properties/jb:property", nm))
{
    if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "teststudio.pwd")  // tsuser1
    {
        selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new password";  // changes password value for "FTP_USER".
    }

    if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "watson.git_pwd")   //github
    {
        selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new passwordx";  // changes password value for "FTP_READ_USER".
    }

    if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "FTP_READ_PASS")   // wtsntro
    {
        selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new_passwordy";  // changes password value for "FTP_PASSWORD".
    }
}

doc.Save(path);  // Save changes.
Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully");
```

Comment: One more thing this is the case when user needs to do it in single file, what to do in case of multiple files.

Comment: If the namespace and schema are the same then it'll work. If the namespace is different then @alexfilipocici's solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the namespace:

```
var nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
if (doc.ChildNodes.Count != 2)
    throw new XmlException("Document is not well formated.");
var serverNode = doc.ChildNodes[1];
nm.AddNamespace("a", serverNode.NamespaceURI);
foreach (XmlNode selectNode in 
    doc.SelectNodes("a:server/a:system-properties/a:property", nm))
{
    // ...
}
```