# Why is this program not accessing child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Here it gets the XML document and individual nodes, and inserts the nodes into a dictionary.

```
//create the xml document obj
XmlDocument inputXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
fileref.isValid = false;
//load the xml document
#region
try
{
    inputXMLDoc.XmlResolver = null;
    inputXMLDoc.Load( strfile );//load the xml file
    string input = inputXMLDoc.OuterXml;//get the string

    Console.WriteLine( "success,loaded XML" );
    logger.Log( "loaded xml:" + strfile );


    fileref.importList = new Dictionary<string, XmlNode>();

    nodeNames = new List<string> { "OrderId", "CustomerId", "CustomerName", "Addresses", "OrderStatus", "DateOrdered", "PaymentTime", "IncludeVAT", "OrderTotalIncVat", "OrderTotalVat", "Currency", "TypeOfSaleId" };

    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach( string name in nodeNames )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Adding xml node " + name );

            if( inputXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName( name ) != null )
            {
                XmlNodeList xlist = inputXMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName( name );

                foreach( XmlNode node in xlist )
                {
                    fileref.importList.Add( name, node );
                    //add individual node within nodelist
                    Console.WriteLine( name );

                }
            } //add specified node from XML doc
            else
            {
                nodeNames.RemoveAt( i );
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Later, the nodes are accessed to save the information to a web service. However, nodes with child nodes within are not showing up this way.

```
 Invoices.Address address = new Invoices.Address();

 XmlNodeList oNodeList = fileref.importList["Addresses"].SelectNodes("/Delivery/Street");
 foreach (XmlNode xn in oNodeList)
 {
     address.Street = xn.InnerText;
 }
```

Sample XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InvoiceOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <OrderId xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">35</OrderId>
  <CustomerId xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">21</CustomerId>
  <CustomerName xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">James Bond</CustomerName>
  <Addresses xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">
    <Delivery>
      <Street>11 Shewell Walk</Street>
      <State />
      <PostalCode>CO1 1WG</PostalCode>
      <PostalArea>Essex</PostalArea>
      <Name />
      <City>Colchester</City>
      <Country>UK</Country>
    </Delivery>
    <Invoice>
      <Street>10 Shewell Walk</Street>
      <State />
      <PostalCode>CO1 1WG</PostalCode>
      <PostalArea>Essex</PostalArea>
      <Name />
      <City>Colchester</City>
      <Country>UK</Country>
    </Invoice>
  </Addresses>
  <OrderStatus xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">Offer</OrderStatus>
  <DateOrdered xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">2015-06-15T14:00:00Z</DateOrdered>
  <PaymentTime xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">14</PaymentTime>
  <IncludeVAT xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices" />
  <OrderTotalIncVat xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">480.0000</OrderTotalIncVat>
  <OrderTotalVat xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">80.0000</OrderTotalVat>
  <Currency xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">
    <Symbol>LOCAL</Symbol>
  </Currency>
  <TypeOfSaleId xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">-100</TypeOfSaleId>
  <InvoiceRows xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices">
    <InvoiceRow>
      <ProductId>18</ProductId>
      <RowId>4665754</RowId>
      <Price>400.0000</Price>
      <Name>17" Laptop Screen</Name>
      <DiscountRate>0.0000</DiscountRate>
      <Quantity>7.0000</Quantity>
      <Cost>0.0000</Cost>
      <InPrice>0.0000</InPrice>
    </InvoiceRow>
  </InvoiceRows>
</InvoiceOrder>
```

Comment: Which XML parser are you using?

Comment: Could you try formatting your code?  It's also unclear what your issue is - what does ' are not showing up this way' mean?  I suspect none of this works because you've ignored the namespace of these elements.  Is there any reason you're using `XmlDocument` rather than LINQ to XML?

Comment: If I run your code without the namespace on the `Addresses` element it works. My XPath is rubbish though so not sure what you need to do to the expression to get the stuff you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is likely that you're ignoring the namespace of the elements you're looking for. There are many questions covering how to do that, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561822/xpath-on-an-xml-document-with-namespace).

That said, `XmlDocument` is a creaky old API and the newer LINQ to XML is a huge improvement - I'd suggest you look into that.

I'm also not sure the dictionary is pulling its weight for such a small number of elements.  You can simply query what you need straight from the XML.  For example, to get all your fields as typed values:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(strfile);      
var order = doc.Elements("InvoiceOrder").Single();

XNamespace ns = "http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices";

var orderId = (int)order.Element(ns + "OrderId");
var customerId = (int)order.Element(ns + "CustomerId");
var customerName = (string)order.Element(ns + "CustomerName");
var orderStatus = (string)order.Element(ns + "OrderStatus");
var dateOrdered = (DateTime)order.Element(ns + "DateOrdered");
var paymentTime = (int)order.Element(ns + "PaymentTime");
var totalIncVat = (decimal)order.Element(ns + "OrderTotalIncVat");
var totalVat = (decimal)order.Element(ns + "OrderTotalVat");
var currency = (string)order.Elements(ns + "Currency").Elements(ns + "Symbol").SingleOrDefault();
var typeOfSaleId = (int)order.Element(ns + "TypeOfSaleId");
```

You can use a similar technique to get map your addresses to your strongly typed `Address` class:

```
var deliveryAddress = order.Elements(ns + "Addresses")
    .Elements(ns + "Delivery")
    .Select(e => new Invoice.Address
    {
        Street = (string)e.Element(ns + "Street"),
        // ....
    })
    .Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is with namespaces. If you specify the namespace for each of those elements then it seems to work. I came to this conclusion with a bit of googling and some experimentation so my explanation might not be spot on so I advise researching the issue further yourself to understand it correctly.

This code will work:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(inputXMLDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices");
var oNodeList = importList["Addresses"].SelectNodes("//ns:Delivery/ns:Street",nsmgr);
```

The reason is (I think) that in your XML document you are specifying a default namespace for your elements (`xmlns="http://24sevenOffice.com/webservices"`) and in your xpath you are not specifying that same namespace. In my code I create a namespace manager with that namespace in and prefix it to the two elements which it now considers to match the ones in your document that have these namespaces.