# Problem adding namespaces to MSXML (using setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', ...))

Tags: namespaces, msxml

A while back, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519416/delphi-msxml-xpath-queries-fail) regarding the usage of namespaces in MSXML. At first, I circumvented the whole thing with the XPath `*[local-name()]`-hack (see my previous post), but having a crisis of conscience I decided to do things the right way. (Doh!)

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.foo.bar mySchema.xsd" xmlns="http://www.foo.bar" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <MyElement>
  </MyElement>
</Root>
```

When I try to add these namespaces using `IXMLDOMDocument3.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', NSString);`, I get the following error:

> "SelectionNamespaces property value is invalid. Only well-formed xmlns
> attributes are allowed.".

When removing the namespace `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.foo.bar mySchema.xsd"`, everything runs smoothly. What am I doing wrong here? Is there an error in the XML? Is MSXML to blame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsi:schemaLocation="..."` is not a namespace definition, it is an attribute of the `<Root>` element which is in xsi namespace.
So removing this from the list of namespaces as you did is already the solution.

Comment: yeah, I guess it makes sense after all. Thanks.